# Custom coordinate reference system

Tags: coordinate-system

I have this information for a custom CRS.

PROJCS["NAD_1983_HARN_Adj_MN_Hubbard_Feet",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_HARN",DATUM["D_North_American_1983_HARN",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500035.7771574167],PARAMETER["False_Northing",100007.154316],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-94.92055555555557],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.000071553661],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",46.80361111111111],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]

How would I enter it in urs code?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange. Please [take the tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about our focused Q&A format, and then edit your question with a little more information -- What is your desired outcome, what have you tried, where are you getting stuck, what application are you using?

Comment: I see now that it would be something like this

Comment: http://epsg.io/26850

Comment: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=46.803611111 +lon_0=-94.9205555556 +k_0=1.000071553661 x_o=152411.2097 +y_0=304822416 +units=us_ft

Comment: I solved it. +proj=tmerc +lat_0=46.803611111 +lon_0=-94.920555556 +k=1.000071553661 +x_0=30482.2416 +y_0=152411.2097 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs  Thanks for the leads